# Adding shop sidebar in single product page

Tags: woocommerce, widget, sidebar

I'm really struggling to add a sidebar in the single product page in Woocommerce. I would like to add a sidebar that could display the shop widget. Is this possible to do? It's a custom theme that I have limited knowledge of.

Comment: That custom theme is woocommerce supported theme ? if yes, then it is possible.

Comment: It's a custom made theme.